# Converting nginx access log bytes to number in Kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

I would like to create a visualization of the sum of bytes sent using the data from my nginx access logs.  When trying to create a "Metric" visualization, I can't use the `bytes` field as a sum because it is a string type.

[image]

And I'm not able to change it under settings.

How do I go about changing this field type to a number/bytes type?

Here is my logstash config for nginx access logs

```
filter {
  if [type] == "nginx-access" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{NGINXACCESS}" }
    }
    geoip {
      source => "clientip"
    }
    useragent {
      source => "agent"
      target => "useragent"
    }
  }
}
```

Since each logstash index is being created as an index, I'm guess I need to change it here.

I tried adding

```
mutate {
  convert => { "bytes" => "integer" }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: After adding the new `mutate` filter, did you wait until a new logstash index was created or did you expect the existing index to change immediately? If you wipe your indices and run logstash again, don't you see your `bytes` field as an integer? Can you also update your question with the `NGINXACCESS` pattern you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  After I stopped logstash, updated the config, deleted all indices, and started logstash, it started showing as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field types are configured using *mappings*, which is configured at the index level and can hardly change. With Logstash, as a new index is created everyday, so if you wan't to change these *mappings* either wait for the next day or delete the current index if you can.

By default these *mappings* are generated automatically by Elasticsearch depending on the syntax of the indexed JSON document and the applied Index Templates:

```
# Type String
{"bytes":"123"}

# Type Integer
{"bytes":123}
```

In the end there are 2 solutions:

- Tune Logstash, to make it generate an integer and let Elasticsearch guess the field type → Use the mutate/convert filter
- Tune Elasticsearch, to force the field `bytes` for the document type `nginx-access` to be of type `integer` → Use Index Template:

Index Template API:

```
PUT _template/logstash-nginx-access
{
  "order": 1,
  "template": "logstash-*",
  "mappings": {
    "nginx-access": {
      "properties": {
        "bytes": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```